# Videocapture from opencv doesn't work for me. What should I do?

Tags: python, docker, opencv, dockerfile, video-capture

I have dockerized my app and I have used `http://nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:23.10-py3` base image. I'll share my dockerfile with you. I am also using Ubuntu.

The problem here is that `videocapture` method from `opencv==4.8.0.74` doesn't work!

It doesn't give me an error but doesn't work!

I also couldn't use opencv newer versions be cause I faced the following error:

module 'cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'DictValue'

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:23.10-py3

COPY requirements.txt /opt/app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /opt/app

# RUN pip uninstall -y opencv-python

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip uninstall -y opencv-python opencv-python-headless

RUN pip install opencv-python==4.8.0.74

RUN mkdir -p /home/amirreza/Desktop/vi/file15

RUN mkdir -p /home/amirreza/Desktop/vi/file16

COPY vi.py /opt/app/vi.py

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

CMD [ "python", "./vi.py" ]
```

My `requirements.txt`:

```
transformers==4.34.0

timm==0.9.7

pytest-shutil
```

The part of my python script:

```
import os
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from transformers import pipeline

def video_to_frames(video_path, frames_dir):

    video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    count = 0

    while video.isOpened():

        ret, frame = video.read()

        if not ret:

            break

        cv2.imwrite(frames_dir + "/{:d}.png".format(count), frame)

        count += 1

    video.release()

    # cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return count

cwd = os.getcwd()

folder = 'videos'

#  video2.mp4 & video1.mp4 path

video1_path = os.path.join(cwd, folder, 'video1.mp4')

video2_path = os.path.join(cwd, folder, 'video2.mp4')


aa='/opt/app/file15'
bb='/opt/app/file16'

os.makedirs('/opt/app/file15', exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs('/opt/app/file16', exist_ok=True)


frames_count_1 = video_to_frames(video1_path, aa)
frames_count_2 = video_to_frames(video2_path, bb)
```

In my script the function doesn't work because the `videocapture` doesn't work (I think)!

Because after running the code still file15 and file16 are empty!

Also my code works truly and it works on Google colab!

Can someone please help me to fix this problem?

I have also tried the following installation but unfortunately it didn't work!

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

By the way is there any problem with python version? Because python is installed from that base image and it's version is 3.10.12.

Or for example does opencv needs any extra libraries to run videocapture method?

Also I printed the `count` variable in the function and the output was 0!

Comment: Your docker config is putting `file15` and `file16` in `/home/amirezza/Desktop/vi`, but your code is putting them in `/opt/app`.  Are you sure your videos were copied into the container?